# argparse short version of option combined incorrectly

Tags: python-3.x, argparse

I have a number of arguments that are being read in using the `argparse` library in python 3. For some reason, the short options are being concatenated with their longer versions. This seems to only happen to certain character combinations. Namely:

```
...    
parser.add_argument("-o" "--remove-stop-words", help="flag to remove stop words and punctuation from abstracts", action="store_true")
parser.add_argument("-t" "--stem-words", help="flag to stem words in abstracts")
...
```

is displayed and interpreted as:

```
usage: test.py [-h] [-o--remove-stop-words] [-t--stem-words T__STEM_WORDS]

optional arguments:

-h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -o--remove-stop-words
                        flag to remove stop words and punctuation from
                        abstracts
  -t--stem-words T__STEM_WORDS
                        flag to stem words in abstracts
```

I haven't found anything in the documentation that would describe why this would be, but please let me know if I missed something. Thanks!

Comment: `"-o" "--remove-stop-words"` is exactly the same string as `"-o--remove-stop-words"` - adjacent string literals get combined.  You want a comma between those, I think.

Comment: Don't know how I missed that. Thanks, it's always the little things.

Answer (score 1):

In case this trips anyone else up, as per [@jasonharper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1709364/jasonharper), make sure to have commas between flag string literals. Otherwise, they are combined.